# Importing Feeds into an entity?

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds, entities, importing-exporting

I am trying to create a store using Ubercart. like most other things on my site, I have a large amount of data stored on a csv file that I downloaded out of PHPmyAdmin from another site (the clients original site), which I need to upload into my new site. I am trying to upload them as products, but the problem is that things like the "List Price", the 'cost", the "sell price", and "SKU" number are entities, and those fields don't show up in the feeds importer. is there a way to import feeds into an entity as well as a field?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 you can acheve this using the [Commerce feeds](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module.
Also check [this tutorial](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/467).

I couldn't find anything similar for Ubercart; maybe back-porting the Commerce feeds module is the only way to go.